# update scroll color to fit darkmode site

Tags: html, css

I have a pre that scroll-able

[image]

As you can see my site is in a darkmode, and that white scroll is ruined it.

I've tried

```
pre {
    background-color: #323338;
    scrollbar-color: #323338 black;
}
```

somehow it's not taking any effects.

Any hints for me ?

---

## Try # 2

```
<pre class="syslogs" style="overflow-y:auto; height:  500px;"> {{ $logs }} </pre>






.syslogs {
    scrollbar-color: #323338 black;
}
```

Comment: `:root { color-scheme: dark; }`. Learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme)

Comment: What browser do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #323338;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [a custom styling for your scrollbars](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-scrollbars).

Note that it's not going to work across all browsers, but it will let you improve their style in Chrome and Firefox.